# How to manage branch level permissions in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

I want to allow access to particular branches with particular individuals who are developers. They may not be able to see other branches which are not assigned to them. Is it possible to practice this scenario in Gitlab? Please help me to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only possibility is to protect from push and merge as in https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html

You cannot hide to different members. Membership is per project, not per branch.